# Влияние наречий меры и степени на написание НЕ с причастиями, на количество Н в суффиксах

Tags: частица-не, причастия, наречия, нн

Помогите, пожалуйста, объяснить ребенку, что при наличии наречий меры и степени (*совсем*, *вовсе*, *абсолютно*, *совершенно*) НЕ с прилагательными пишется слитно, но одновременно усилительными конструкциями для раздельного написания с НЕ в разных учебниках указываются «вовсе не», реже «совсем не».

> Этот случай вовсе не уникальный.
> (Отрицательная конструкция «вовсе не»).

или

> Этот случай вовсе неуникальный.
> («Вовсе» — наречие меры и степени).

В справочнике Розенталя двоякое написание допускают наречия *совсем*, *вовсе*, в справочнике Лопатина — *абсолютно*, *совершенно*.
Как писать правильно?

> Вовсе не прочитанная рукопись.
> Вовсе непрочитанная рукопись.

> Совершенно непрочитанная рукопись.
> Совершенно не прочитанная мною рукопись.

В справочнике Розенталя: «При использовании в качестве пояснительных слов наречий меры и степени (совершенно, совсем, вовсе и др.) частица не с причастием пишется слитно».

На что ориентироваться школьнику? На справочник Лопатина или на справочник Розенталя?

Является ли причастие + наречие меры и степени причастным оборотом, если НЕ с причастным оборотом пишется раздельно, а НЕ с причастием + наречие меры и степени (по Розенталю) пишутся слитно?

> Цифры, совсем не проверенные.
> (Это причастный оборот?)

или

> Цифры, совсем непроверенные.

«Костюм, абсолютно рваный, был выкинут» или «Костюм, абсолютно рванный, был выкинут»?

Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Слово ‟вовсе” не является наречием меры; а является двумя разными частицами.
**Первая частица** — частица, которая предшествует противоположной оценке по отношению к другой оценке, которая была озвучена ранее в контексте или подразумевалась. Взгляните на примеры:

— Это был отличный фильм.
— Мне так не показалось, фильм был вовсе не отличный.

— Ты думаешь о том вреде, что я тебе причинил.
— Вовсе нет, я уже забыл об этом.

— Ах ты хулиган!
— Я вовсе не хулиган, я случайно разбил это стекло.

Причастия и прилагательные с такой вот частицей пишутся раздельно. Вот несколько примеров:

— Задача была легкая.
— А по-моему, вовсе не легкая.

— Я ему верю.
— А я нет, он был вовсе не искренним.

— Мой брат известный человек.
— Твой брат вовсе не известный.

— Ты просто слишком беден.
— Я вовсе не беден, мой доход чуть ниже среднего.

**Вторая частица.** Назовем её ‟градационная”. Взгляните на предложение: ‟Он постоянно опаздывал, а сегодня и вовсе пришел пьяным”. Сначала дается некая информация, которая производит определенное впечатление, а потом дается еще некая информация, которая усиливает это впечатление. Так вот, градационная частица ‟вовсе” стоит перед второй усиливающей частью информации. Взгляните на примеры:

Он много тренировался, стал иногда выдавать равные партии, а затем и вовсе выигрывать.
Он стал много пропускать, а затем и вовсе проиграл нокаутом.
Он был груб с ней, а затем и вовсе стал бить.

После таких частиц, частица ‟не” всегда пишется слитно. Вот несколько примеров:
Авторами этих работ являются менее популярные, или вовсе неизвестные, авторы.
Этот фильм скучноват, а тот и вовсе неинтересный.
Эта задача трудная, а то и вовсе невыполнимая.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ:**
Также слово ‟вовсе” может быть наречием характеристики действия. Вот несколько примеров:
С той ночи, как Нильс подслушал разговор сов, он вовсе перестал надеяться, что когда-нибудь станет человеком. (‟Вовсе” здесь = ‟совсем”, ‟полностью” и т.д.)
Я раньше никогда не встречал, да и не слышал вовсе, чтобы женщина надевала на свидание удобную обувь. (‟Вовсе” здесь = ‟совсем”, ‟полностью” и т.д.)

Comment: В справочнике Розенталя:             http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80 При использовании в качестве пояснительных слов наречий меры и степени (весьма, крайне, очень, почти, совсем, ВОВСЕ и др.) частица не с причастием пишется слитно.

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, на приведённых мной примерах. Как писать правильно?

Comment: Я написал только про ‟вовсе”. Еще раз, ‟вовсе” не является наречием меры и степени, — это ошибка у Розенталя.  В предложении: ‟Этот случай вовсе не уникальный” — ‟вовсе” является частицей, которая предшествует противоположной оценке, и ‟не” пишется раздельно. В контексте, перед этим предложением, кто-то считает этот случай уникальным, а в вашем предложении высказывается противоположная оценка.  Про остальное, скорее всего, потом напишу, но не сегодня и не завтра.